# tvos: change focused color of UIButton

Tags: colors, background, uibutton, focus, tvos

How to change default white color of tvos swift UIButton focus selection?

```
override func didUpdateFocus(in context: UIFocusUpdateContext, with coordinator: UIFocusAnimationCoordinator) {
    if let nextFocusedView = context.nextFocusedView {
        playAllOutlet.backgroundColor  = UIColor.red
        shuffleBtnOutlet.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
    
    }
    
    if let previousFocusView = context.previouslyFocusedView {
           playAllOutlet.backgroundColor  = UIColor.red
        shuffleBtnOutlet.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
    }
}
```

But background when button is focused is still white